# rails: user accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using omniauth with facebook log in integration on my web application. So we have users, but how do we create profiles?

What is an easy way to create user profiles that let them list their bio, where they live etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First profiles, then add omniautho.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2